# Can't access all files in subfolder

Tags: ios, swift

I want to access all files (photos) in photos folder. But it throws an error. 
When I delete ("/photos") it access all context including p.list etc but I want to get all context in just photo folder.

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!+("/photos")

let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

for item in items {
            if item.hasPrefix("nssl") {
                pictures.append(item)
            }
        }
```

screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode a yellow folder is a virtual group, not a real folder. Real folders are blue.
To create a real folder drag a folder with images into the project navigator and select `Create Folder References`.

You can get all jpg files easily with

```
if let items = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension "jpg", subdirectory: "photos") {
   let nsslPictures = items.filter{ $0.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix("nssl") }
   pictures.append(contentsOf: nsslPictures)
}
```

Consider that `nsslPictures` is an array of `URL`, not `String`

Comment: thank you. İf I created real folder my code worked right? But we moslty deal with yellow folders.

Comment: The yellow groups – which are not folders – won't appear in the application bundle.